# tree rebuilds when keyboard shows

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive, rebuild

I'm using responsive_sizer package for my app..

my whole tree is rebuilt when the keyboard opens with a textfield.

Here the code of the textfield :

```
class ProfileNameTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileNameTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileNameTextFieldState createState() => _ProfileNameTextFieldState();
}

class _ProfileNameTextFieldState extends State<ProfileNameTextField> {
  TextEditingController? _controller;
  String _previousName = "";
  FocusNode? _focusNode;
  final String _forbiddenCharacters = "1234567890&)°(+=/,;.£\$*€<>\_#@";
  Widget _subText = Container();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _previousName = CloudUser.instance.username;
    _controller!.text = CloudUser.instance.username;
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    _focusNode!.addListener(() {
      if(!_focusNode!.hasFocus) {
        print("Focus on name textfield is lost");
        _onSubmitted(_controller!.text);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    _focusNode!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget? _suffix;


    switch(Provider.of<LoadingProvider>(context).state) {
      case LoadingState.busy:
        _suffix = SpinKitRing(
          color: Theme
              .of(context)
              .primaryColor,
          lineWidth: 2,
          size: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.fontSize!
        );
        break;
      case LoadingState.idle:
        _suffix = Container();
        break;
    }

    return CustomTextContainer(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: _giveFocus,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children:
                [
                  Text(
                      "Prénom",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!.fontSize!.sp
                      )
                  ),
                  Container(height: Sizer().heightSmallSpace),
                  Container(height: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.fontSize,
                    child: Row(children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          controller: _controller,
                          onSubmitted: _onSubmitted,
                          focusNode: _focusNode,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              isDense: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          ),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.fontSize!.sp
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),),
                      _suffix,
                    ]),
                  ),
                  Container(height: Sizer().heightSmallSpace),
                  Row(children: [
                    Spacer(),
                    Container(
                        height: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.fontSize!*1.2,
                        child: Center(child: _subText)),
                  ]),
                  Container(height: Sizer().heightSmallSpace),
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }

  _onSubmitted(String username) {
    RegExp regExp = RegExp('[' + _forbiddenCharacters + ']');
    if(!regExp.hasMatch(username)) {
      if(_previousName != username) {
        print("name is " + username);
        _previousName = username;
        setState(() {
          _subText = Container();
        });
        Provider.of<LoadingProvider>(context, listen: false).update('username', username).then((result) {
          if(result) {
            CloudUser.instance.username = username;
            setState(() {
              _subText = Text(
                "Enregistré",
                style: Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .subtitle1!
                    .copyWith(
                    color: color.success,
                    fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.fontSize!.sp
                ),
              );
            });
          }
          else
            setState(() {
              _subText = Text(
                "Erreur serveur",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
                    color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                    fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.fontSize!.sp
                ),
              );
            });
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _subText = Text(
          "Caractères interdits",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(
              color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
              fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.fontSize!.sp
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        );
      });
    }
  }

  _giveFocus() {
    _focusNode!.requestFocus();
  }
}
```

Within Sizer(), i have :

```
double padding = 2.h;

  double widgetHeight = 8.h;

  double iconButton = 4.h;

  double radius = 15;

  double lineWidth = 3.h;

  double heightSpace = 3.h;

  double heightSmallSpace = 0.9.h;

  double gridSpacing = 0.3.h;

  double widthSpace = 1.25.w;
```

ProfileNameTextField is included in

```
class _ProfileControllerState extends State<ProfileController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        child: Column(
            children: [
              ProfileAppBar(
                onSetting: _onSetting,
              ),
              Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Sizer().padding/3),
                      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                      child: Scrollbar(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Sizer().padding*2/3),
                                  child: Column(children:
                                  [
                                    Container(height: Sizer().heightSpace),
                                    SvgPicture.asset(
                                      "assets/icons/phone_kisses.svg",
                                      height: Sizer().widgetHeight*3,
                                      width: Sizer().getCustomWidth(66),
                                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                    ),
                                    _space(),
                                    ChangeNotifierProvider<LoadingProvider>(
                                      create: (BuildContext context) => LoadingProvider(),
                                      child: ProfileNameTextField(),
                                    ),
```

I have this problem since the import of the responsive_sizer... I do not understand where the problem can come from.
I tried resizetoavoidbottominset but nothing changed.

Comment: I don't know this package but I had a very similar issue recently. What I learned is that if a widget's build method uses `MediaQuery.of(context).size` (which can be the case with this packege) build will be triggered whenever the screen size changes. And keyboard opening is animated, meaning multiple rebuilds.

Comment: But MediaQuery is an essential part of responsive app. I use it everywhere in my app and have only the problem here. What was your workaround? Delete MediaQuery call?

Comment: You can't do much about it, when keyboard is opened, it is essential that your UI is updated, since the available space is changing. In general you don't need to worry about rebuilds, Flutter is designed in a way that it can handle it.

Comment: For example if you start entering data to a textfield, you don't want it to be hidden by the opening keyboard.

Comment: My case was a little annoying, it was related to orientation. Flutter's default orientation handling is not depending on sensor data, but simply comparing whether current width is larger or smaller than height. And on devices with smaller screen the appearing keyboard resulted in changing orientation, so a rebuild was triggered, which closed the keyboard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It's not coming from MediaQuery, but from the Responsive_sizer package.

When I open the keyboard, I actually update the height and width. But this package must necessarily encompass your MaterialApp in the following way:

```
    MaterialApp(
 home: ResponsiveSizer(
   builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
     return const HomePage();
   },
 ),
);
```

And that's the problem. Under my homepage, I have a stream to see if the user is logged in, which then leads to the profile page, among other things. I don't want it to reload, I just want the profile to reload.

My solution: I use MediaQuery in a similar way to Responsive_sizer.... instead of using the .h and .w package, I use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height and its counterpart. The same thing for the font size.

I hope this can help those who have the same problem as me on this package,
good evening.